# Hibernate createQuery() for Date_add

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hsqldb, dateadd, createquery

I am trying to implement the following SQL query in hibernate HSQL. Instead of value '7' I have to pass a dynamic value 'delivery'.

```
SELECT quote_key , delivery_date 
  FROM Orders 
  WHERE delivery_date >= DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL '-7' DAY);
```

DAO Layer:

```
String sql = " FROM Orders where deliveryDate >= DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -(:delivery) " + " DAY)";

Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
query.setParameter("delivery", delivery);
List<Orders> mergedData = query.list();
```

I am getting the following error:

> unexpected token: DAY

for any syntax I try. Is there any way to implement it using HSQL itself rather than Native SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CREATE FUNCTION syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html) to create a function that will take that integer parameter, create your own dialect and use the JPQL `function('myfunction', :param)`, as described [in this article](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/database-functions/).

Otherwise you will have to use native SQL.